# Como ler as sub página no graph API

Tags: facebook

Preciso fazer uma aplicação utilizando `php` e `python`, porém, nesse momento, estou entendendo como funciona o `graph API`. Utilizando o sistema vi que o `graph API` para na próxima página e não mostra os demais amigos.

Como faço para ler toda a lista de usuários que tenho no *facebook*?